# Insert child table record with parent id

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-server-2008, oracle10g, oracle11g

I am having the two tables parent and child table.I want to insert the parent and child table record simultaneously. But the child table having the parent id. Sorry for my English.

```
Table 1
=======
fld_id name desc
 1     sasi new_customer
 2     arun old_customer


Table 2
=======
fld_id fld_parent_id  product
 1       1             Dress
 2       1             watch
 3       1             phone
 4       2             Clock
 5       2             pen

My input value like this
========================

1,sasi ,Dress|watch|phone
2,Arun ,Clock|pen
```

Please help me to do this..

Comment: You might be able to use an Object Relationship Mapping scheme but ultimately you have to save the parent object first and then the children.

Comment: You have this tagged both sql server and oracle, what database are you using?

Comment: bluefeet dear dude am using oracle and sqlserver.Can you give me the solution either oracle or sqlserver.

Comment: Insert first in the Parent table and then in the child table. Put the two inserts in a single SQL script and run the script instead. Not sure how else you could achieve what you want to.

Answer (score 0):

```
begin

insert into parent_table;  --insert statement for parent table
insert into child table ;  --insert statement for child table

commit;
end;
```